# MongoBD $arrayElemAt returning wrong values

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have this simple `$project` in my aggregation query to return the first image (string) element of **each** product item and store it in the `first` field.

```
{
    $project: {
      'products._id': 1,
      'products.images': 1,
      'products.first': { $arrayElemAt: ['$products.images', 0] },
    },
  }
```

However, when I execute the query, it sets the `first` field to the value entire images array of the first product.

Desired Result:

```
{
  "_id": "60d9adda7f017440403d57fb",
  "products": [
    {
      "_id": "5e48a95545f3350017aecce0",
      "images": ["image1","image2"],
      "first": "image1"
    },
    {
      "_id": "5e4c0b0986c1d0001757ae06",
      "images": ["image3"],
      "first": "image3"
    },
    {
      "_id": "5e4c0e1c86c1d0001757ae07",
      "images": ["image4"],
      "first": "image4"
    }
  ]
}
```

Actual Result:

```
{
  "_id": "60d9adda7f017440403d57fb",
  "products": [
    {
      "_id": "5e48a95545f3350017aecce0",
      "images": ["image1","image2"],
      "first": ["image1", "image2"]
    },
    {
      "_id": "5e4c0b0986c1d0001757ae06",
      "images": ["image3"],
      "first": ["image1", "image2"]
    },
    {
      "_id": "5e4c0e1c86c1d0001757ae07",
      "images": ["image4"],
      "first": ["image1", "image2"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Please, how can I resolve this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is some disscussion about it [here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-37246) and [here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/DOCS-12068). This is a problem of field path expression so you can't project that way. To get your expected output, you can use [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      products: {
        $map: {
          input: "$products",
          as: "product",
          in: {
            _id: "$$product._id",
            images: "$$product.images",
            first: {
              "$arrayElemAt": [ "$$product.images", 0 ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
  }
])
```

[Mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Khh_wggE3kz)

Comment: This aggregate query works with MongoDB v4.4 or higher only. The `$first` aggregate array operator is a feature introduced with v4.4.

Comment: I don't use `$first` operator. It's just "first", a field name that op used.

Comment: I see my comment is based upon assumption the instead of using `$arrayElemAt`  you can use `$first` (which is a feature of MongoDB v4.4). The query as it is works fine with `$arrayElemAt` with earlier versions. _My mistake!_